# Cant install any python packages

Tags: python, import, pycharm, package

Im trying to install python packages
I tried "pip install" in my cmd
Then i tried PyCharm settings but it always give me message "
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file cannot be found" and the following Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 
114, in main
do_install(pkgs)
File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 
59, in do_install
run_pip(['install'] + pkgs)
File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 
73, in run_pip
runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
File "D:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
File "D:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
File "D:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
sys.exit(_main())
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 56, in 
main
cmd_name, cmd_args = parse_command(args)
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 
60, in parse_command
general_options, args_else = parser.parse_args(args)
File "D:\python\lib\optparse.py", line 1371, in parse_args
values = self.get_default_values()
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 289, 
in get_default_values
self.config.load()
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 
134, in load
self._load_config_files()
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 
256, in _load_config_files
config_files = dict(self.iter_config_files())
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 
359, in iter_config_files
config_files = get_configuration_files()
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 
75, in get_configuration_files
for path in appdirs.site_config_dirs('pip')
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 
34, in site_config_dirs
dirval = _appdirs.site_config_dir(appname, appauthor=False, multipath=True)
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 243, in 
site_config_dir
path = site_data_dir(appname, appauthor)
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 138, in 
site_data_dir
path = os.path.normpath(_get_win_folder("CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA"))
File "D:\PyProj\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 486, in 
_get_win_folder_from_registry
dir, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, shell_folder_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file cannot be found
```

Comment: please translate the error msg to english

Comment: its "The specified file cannot be found"